# SHA256 digest in perl

Tags: perl, hash, md5, sha, sha256

I need to do SHA256 hashing of email addresses and I need the result as a String.

I tried the following:

```
  use Digest::SHA qw(sha256);
  my $data = 'swaranga@gmail.com';
  my $digest = sha256($data);

  print $digest;
```

But it prints something like:

```
B/D6i1Î¼û^Þ©Q;¢Þ
```

I need the output as follows:

```
cbc41284e23c8c7ed98f589b6d6ebfd6
```

The above hash is generated using SHA256 generator of [Apache DigestUtils](http://commons.apache.org/codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/digest/DigestUtils.html).

What am I doing wrong? I am a newbie in perl, so excuse if it is something silly.

Thanks.

Comment: **MD5** tag should be added to this question

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`cbc41284e23c8c7ed98f589b6d6ebfd6` is **MD5** for `swaranga@gmail.com`, not **SHA-256**

---

**SHA** encryptions for `swaranga@gmail.com` >>

```
 SHA-1:            3a3be7013e297e28d24979aadc4ae75d84ce0844
 SHA-256:          0947300f280d422f4418366931cebcfbd17f5ede1507a951153b0f15a21c10de
 SHA-384:          34c01f3956aac32aacae1a6cf67f8a66d441af06c9d36f580ce4be5b234b5399cd879231c49db5bec269309582c19432
 SHA-512:          db1aa053dd9ee191b091abbcb8bead2ec69a1ab2664bb1deeeedbdb49b25e7bc7680a7659ae88c046afdabf1e35ed0e068763f8754b369bfade69cf21f65d166
 SHA-1   (Base64): OjvnAT4pfijSSXmq3ErnXYTOCEQ=
 SHA-256 (Base64): CUcwDygNQi9EGDZpMc68+9F/Xt4VB6lRFTsPFaIcEN4=
 SHA-384 (Base64): NMAfOVaqwyqsrhps9n+KZtRBrwbJ029YDOS+WyNLU5nNh5IxxJ21vsJpMJWCwZQy
 SHA-512 (Base64): 2xqgU92e4ZGwkau8uL6tLsaaGrJmS7He7u29tJsl57x2gKdlmuiMBGr9q/HjXtDgaHY/h1Szab+t5pzyH2XRZg==
```

---

If you sure you want to use **SHA-256** and you are looking for **HEX** output, then try this one:

***Script:***

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use Digest::SHA qw(sha256);
print unpack("H*", sha256('swaranga@gmail.com')), "\n";
```

or

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use Digest::SHA qw(sha256_hex);
print sha256_hex('swaranga@gmail.com'), "\n";
```

***Output:***

```
0947300f280d422f4418366931cebcfbd17f5ede1507a951153b0f15a21c10de
```

---

And if you want **MD5** with **HEX** output, then try this one:

***Script:***

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use Digest::MD5 qw(md5);
print unpack("H*", md5('swaranga@gmail.com')), "\n";
```

or

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use Digest::MD5 qw(md5_hex);
print md5_hex('swaranga@gmail.com'), "\n";
```

***Output:***

```
cbc41284e23c8c7ed98f589b6d6ebfd6
```

Answer (score 6):

You probably want `Digest::SHA qw(sha256_hex)`  From CPAN's [Digest::SHA](http://search.cpan.org/~mshelor/Digest-SHA-5.71/lib/Digest/SHA.pm) page

> Logically joins the arguments into a single string, and returns its
>   SHA-1/224/256/384/512 digest encoded as a hexadecimal string.