# How to create a SHA-256 hash of a string in Mason code?

Tags: perl, sha, mason

I am trying to create a SHA-256 hash of a string in
[`Mason`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mason)
by following the answers to the *Stack Overflow* question
[*SHA256 digest in perl*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9991757/sha256-digest-in-perl)
and using the
[`Digest::SHA`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Digest::SHA) module

These are the contents of the file `abc.mi` that contains that code:

```
use Digest::SHA qw(sha256_hex);
<%init>
    my $message = 'random content';
    my $encryptedMsg = sha256_hex($message);
</%init>
```

But it's throwing the following error:

```
Undefined subroutine &Safe::Root0::HTML::Mason::Commands::sha256_hex called
```

Any idea why it is considering `sha256_hex` as undefined even though I defined it at the beginning of the file itself?

Has this got something to do with the fact this is Mason code with extension `.mi`?

========== EDIT ==========

Here is the solution to my query, after going through the answers posted for this question.

```
<%init>
    my $message = 'random content';
    my $encryptedMsg = Digest::SHA::sha256_hex($message);
</%init>
```

Comment: This is a comment rather than an answer because I am guessing. But it's a very informed guess, and I am sure that anything outside *Mason* markup `<%tag> ... </%tag>` is copied literally, just like PHP. I'm unsure whether it's possible to `use` modules from within a Mason template, but it seems wrong in every way even if it works. Try moving `use Digest::SHA qw(sha256_hex)` to your Perl code.

Comment: @Borodin: Your assumptions are all correct. And you can use Perl modules within Mason templates and it's a terrible idea for all the obvious reasons. But it's how Mason systems seem to be written. I'm speaking as someone who is currently working on a huge Mason codebase that powers one of the UK's best-known web sites.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Mason, your Perl code needs to be inside your tags. Anything outside of a tag is just content to be included in the output. So you want something like:

```
<%init>
  use Digest::SHA qw(sha256_hex);
  my $message = 'random content';
  my $encryptedMsg = sha256_hex($message);
</%init>
```

Comment: Doing that, my previous error goes away. But I'm still getting a different error now. It says 'Can't locate Digest/SHA.pm in @INC" : https://paste.kde.org/pcm80yyvl

Comment: @SanjibanBairagya: If you have a new question, then you should ask it in a new post. But the error message is pretty clear. It looks like Digest::SHA isn't installed on your system. Digest::SHA was added to the standard Perl distribution for Perl 5.10. You are using Perl 5.8. I don't know why you're using such an old version of Perl, but if you want to stick with that version, then you'll need to install Digest::SHA from CPAN.

Comment: Okay. I just called the function directly (without "use"-ing in the beginning) and it worked without having to install any modules. Thanks for your answer.